# How to tell if Blender has crashed?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am unsure whether or not Blender has crashed / stalled.
The screen, especially the timer, haven't changed in over an hour (while usually the timer tells you how much time has elapsed since rendering began).
But I'm thinking, hey, maybe the timer's just slowing down because it's processing and thinking too hard to update?

[image]

Is there a way to know? As far as I know, when I hover over the different buttons in the properties panel, they change color (and so does the X for cancelling rendering), so it might just be working (that's what indicates my Activity Monitor as well, as seen in the image below).

[image]

But what's a certain way to know whether or not Blender has stalled / crash?

Comment: One hour seems too much for me. Try to clic that buttons, the File button for instance. If the menu opens, then Blender is not crashed. Anyway, the render might failed, which is rare in CPU rendering. Make some render with low samples/resolution for testing your scene before the final render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the interface is still responsive, Blender hasn't crashed (yet). But in this case is engaged on some heavy computing.

In this case the issue is that you are trying to render using an insane number of samples!

You've set up 1000 samples but have the square samples box enabled, that will make the number 1,000,000 (1000 samples x 1000).

[image]

A million samples will require massive computing power!

Uncheck the square samples box and bring the number of samples to a reasonable number...

Comment: I went outside for a few hours, and when I came back there was some progress. Then it ended up rendering the image completely, and took 8 hours total to do so. To a certain extent, it was well worth it, as I've rarely had so few fireflies on a Cycles render! The result was really very good quality which isn't always the case with Cycles.

Comment: Dealing with noise becomes  always a compromise between the realities of rendering times and computing power, and aesthetics.

Comment: Definitely. I wonder if other 3D programs have a rendering engine that gives results as good as Cycles but with less computer time required...

Comment: that should be a new question... ;)  http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/render-engine-comparison-cycles-vs-giants/