# Bad Render. Too much Noise. Low Light

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've been using blender for quite sometime. But I have most my "Disabilities" in the NODE/Material/Lighting area.

I tried most REDUCE NOISE tutorials, tried TOP X Tricks to take out fireflies, but it seems that each case is a case and I cannot achieve approximate results to other people in the same sample size. For example, a person achieves a perfect render a 50 samples. I would have to put 500 samples to try achieve the same result... It's very frustrating.

The lighting inside the "DEN" seems too low, compared to the outside light intensity.

I have a Intel 2600K Processor, G.Skill.Sniper.8GB.1600Mhz RAM, GTX970 G1.Gigabyte Graphics card.

Blender File: http://www.mediafire.com/download/8gd70c8aonbr4ss/BEAR-Radio.blend
(might be missing one or two texture images for the Radio. Just delete that material and it should assume another Radio Material)

Comment: use "square samples" in the render panel "sampling section"

Comment: Inspecting your file I see there's no lights in your 'DefaultScene' which I presume is the one you are trying to render. Your world node setup is also empty which leads to a black background. General rule of thumb for cycles is: **'Hard to find' light sources generate noise and fireflies**. That means avoid very small lamp sizes, light sources hidden behind objects, lots of indirect light from far away or occluded sources.

Comment: yes as @DuarteFarrajotaRamos said you need to remake your scene. After that squared samples. And you may obtain that : https://i.gyazo.com/6bd1b655cc58b11960147fcbf6aeb95f.png

Comment: @lemon I think you meant "remake your world", not scene. Don't scare the user ;)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers. I'm going to try Duarte's Advice. Altho, what's the point of remaking world? What would that achieve? This is an honest question, since I'm still learning blender.
 In my file, I got a CUBE with FAKE sky material that EMITS blue light. That cube is all around the objects and it renders fine, not like yours. Now I have an Issue. When I check Square Samples, Blender renders super slow. Is this for final render only? I also got various blender files, for each Anim that I'm rendering (lots of things tends to crash more). That's why I had no WORLD.

Comment: Square samples does not mean that the samples take the form of a square, but it means that the number of samples is multiplied by itself. So if you have 100 samples and square them you end up with 10 000 samples... @ lemon Please be cautious when using that option (or recommending its usage) read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48128/how-to-tell-if-blender-has-crashed/48172#48172

Comment: I see, like 100². Wouldn't that be like just putting the X² result from scratch? How is one better from the other? Also, what about the REMAKE SCENE part? I don't really understand what this means.

Thanks all for the answers. I appreaciate them, but I still don't understand some of them. Real noob here :(

Comment: Start with something like 250 samples NOT SQUARED and see how that goes... Bring up the resolution to 100%, Set the lights to use nodes and set the intensity to a higher number. Do not be afraid to use values in the thousands for intensity...

Comment: Hey @cegaton, I've been using the Squared Samples and I think it's only for Preview/Review of SCENE. I guess it's nothing more that putting the Squared number itself, I would assume. But just quicker. I already been playing around the light intensity alot too and the 100% is not necessary since I'm rendering in 720p. Unless it's better quality to have 720p from scratch and 100% in resolution. Should I use portals in the scene? Considering I have the GROUND object that emits light and CLOSES the object within it's boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scenes where the light bounces around a lot (think indoor scenes) you're going to need more samples.  Renders that look good at only 50 samples are probably more open than yours.

That being said, setting max bounces to 0 will get rid of your fireflies, but you will also lose all of the nice bounce lighting.  And at that point you might as well use the blender internal.  My advice is to turn up your samples and go get a cup of coffee.  I wouldn't worry about it.