# Cycles Render Delays to Render the First Frame of Animation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I’m trying to render an animation, and whenever a frame starts to render, Blender freezes for around 20 seconds before doing any rendering. Like, even before loading resources. I can’t even close the render window. It just freezes.

This is a brand new computer, with an 8-Core Ryzen CPU, GTX 1650, and 32 GB of 3600 MHz RAM. It’s not a system specs issue. Once it starts loading resources, the render takes around 7 seconds.
[image]

It does this for every frame, and nearly quadruples the render time. My old laptop renders things faster than this.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I’ve tried copying things into a new project, and it doesn’t change. Rendering the default cube is much faster, but still has about a second or two of freeze before the render starts.

Switching to GPU rendering takes almost the exact same time. Maybe a few seconds longer, even.

[image]

This is what my task manager looks like while it’s frozen.

I am using Cycles, but the same thing happens with Eevee.

Here is my project file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14J6NJOCtXr4x4eirqrb8Ude1WhHZx1E2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show a [clear] image specifying the use of you GPU? Perhaps with larger font.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bVZA1Pb Like this?

Comment: Is the interface responsive? How complex is the scene? It is possible that blender has not crashed, but it needs to do heavy computing before starting to render. How long did you wait? What is the number of samples you are using? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48128/how-to-tell-if-blender-has-crashed/48172#48172

Comment: It appears responsive, but if I actually click anything it tells me "not responding". It's a very small scene. Just a robotics field and a robot object. I'm using 16 samples in the render, and 5 in the viewport. It freezes for about 20 seconds. If I open another instance of Blender and render some other frames simultaneously, both renderers have the same issue, but they both run at the same speed as when only one was running.

Comment: Hard to help without info. Please [edit] your question and add more information.

Comment: @susu I have edited the OP to include the project file.

Comment: I recommend looking into the console debug. This does sound a little weird

Comment: You have a big scene (close to 8 million faces). Before rendering blender needs to create VBO and other processes, those can take some time to compute. It is normal that there is a lag before the rendering starts showing in the screen.